# Are there any rules how to build the diminutive?

Tags: diminutive, suffix

We build a diminutive by adding the suffix *-lein* or *-chen*. For some nouns one is preferred over the other whereas with other nouns both may be used.

**Examples:**

```
der Tisch | das Tischlein | das Tischchen
das Brot  |       -         das Brötchen
der Bach  | das Bächlein  |     -
```

In *Hochdeutsch* there is a tendency to prefer  *-chen* whereas regionally the suffix corresponding the *-lein*-form (e.g. *-li* Swiss, *-le* Swabian) is used.

Apart from that, are there any rules that define which suffix to use?

Comment: Isn't the form with "-le" the normal, non-diminutive form in Swabian? ;)

Comment: Oh no, *"-le"* still is a diminutive in Swabia - but be careful with *"Brötle"* - that's a cookie and not a *"Weckle"* (the latter being *"Brötchen"*) ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my experience, for Hochdeutsch, "-lein" nowadays is often the exception that you would fall back to in case the more common "-chen" doesn't work, cf. "Bächlein" (because "Bächchen" would be impossible to pronounce even for native speakers).

An a/o/u vowel often changes to their corresponding umlaut:

> Bach -> Bächlein
>
> Brot -> Brötchen
>
> Punkt -> Pünktchen

Additionally, if the last letter is a vowel, it is often omitted when forming a diminutive:

> Schraube -> Schräubchen
>
> Katze -> Kätzchen

There's also a separate diminutive "-i/-y" form mainly used with person names:

> Hans -> Hansi
>
> Fred -> Fredi
>
> Thomas -> Tommy

Some examples of both Hochdeutsch and dialects can be found on [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutivaffix#Beispiele)

Comment: And finally there are the Bavarian diminutives that are made with `-erl`, but *do not* change the stem's vowel: Bacherl, Punkterl, Katzerl, Dutterl, Manschgerl, …

Comment: Not just when last letter is a vowel. *Gärtchen* not *Gärtenchen*.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, in Switzerland we use only "li". If the last vovel is  "a" "o" or "u" it gets to the corresponding umlaut "ä" "ö" or "ü"

- Hund: Hündli
- Brot: Brötli
- Elefant: Elefäntli

But there are also exceptions like

- Sou : Söili
- Bogä: Bögeli/Bögli